# MySQL Trigger - Don't accept record update if outside in range

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create (what I think) should be a basic trigger.

Essentially if someone tries putting a value in for a record that is outside the range of the trigger, then it would refuse the update.

Table is called: People

Field concerned is: age

```
 CREATE TRIGGER max_age_trigger
 BEFORE UPDATE
 ON People
 FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     IF People.age <0 OR People.age>150 THEN
       CALL 'Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)';
    END IF;
 END
```

MySQL is throwing an error at line 7. However i'm not understanding where i'm going wrong. I'm new to triggers and still getting my head around it.

If you could help/assist me in my code, that would be of great help :)

Comment: CALL doesn't have sp name specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an error and stop processing, use `SIGNAL`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER max_age_trigger BEFORE UPDATE
ON People
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF People.age <0 OR People.age>150 THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)';
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thanks, but this throws the following error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''46000'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: The age is out of range (0 > 150)' at line 6